# How to extract h1 tag text with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to understand how to extract a h1 tag text which contains many others tags in it using beautiful soup :

```html
<h1 class="listing-name">
Hôtel Vevey 
<span class="entry-feedbacks-summary-title-rating-stars-container bootstrap">
<span class="entry-feedbacks-summary-title-rating-stars entry-feedbacks-summary-title-rating-stars-empty" data-container=".entry-feedbacks-summary-title-rating-stars-container" data-content="Il n'y a pas encore d'avis de clients à propos de Astra Hôtel Vevey 4*sup. Cliquez pour évaluer." data-placement="right" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-original-title="" title="">
<a class="feedback-login-link entry-feedbacks-header-link" href="/auth/localch?origin=https%3A%2F%2Ftel.local.ch%2Ffr%2Fd%2FVevey%2F1800%2FHotel%2FAstra-Hotel-Vevey-4sup-SVGb8b5z-QdrzGTddmyAAg%3Fwhat%3DHotel%26where%3DVaud%2B%2528Canton%2529%23entry-feedbacks-bottom-rate-button"><span class="entry-feedback-rating-star">
<i class="icon-star-outline entry-feedback-rating-star-empty"></i>
</span>
<span class="entry-feedback-rating-star">
<i class="icon-star-outline entry-feedback-rating-star-empty"></i>
</span>
<span class="entry-feedback-rating-star">
<i class="icon-star-outline entry-feedback-rating-star-empty"></i>
</span>
<span class="entry-feedback-rating-star">
<i class="icon-star-outline entry-feedback-rating-star-empty"></i>
</span>
<span class="entry-feedback-rating-star">
<i class="icon-star-outline entry-feedback-rating-star-empty"></i>
</span>

</a></span>

</span>
</h1>
```

I'm trying to extract the text JUST after the h1 tag "hôtel Vevey".

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://tel.local.ch/fr/d/Vevey/1800/Hotel/Astra-Hotel-Vevey-4sup-SVGb8b5z-QdrzGTddmyAAg?what=Hotel&where=Vaud+%28Canton%29"
get_url = requests.get(url)
get_text = get_url.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_text, "html.parser")

company = soup.find_next('h1', 'class:listing-name')


print(company)
```

It returns me "none"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the current link that you have provided you can get it like this:

```
company = soup.select('h1.listing-name')[0].text.strip()
print(company)
```

Output:

```
Astra Hôtel Vevey 4*sup
```

Comment: Thanks ! I did try this one but I did not think about the strip!

Answer (score 6):

Try using a dictionary:

```
company = soup.find('h1', {'class' : 'listing-name'})
```

Or the following:

```
company = soup.find('h1', class_ ='listing-name')
```

Note the underscore after class. This is because class is a reserved word in python.

More info can be found here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attrs

Comment: soup.select(): 1000 loops, best of 3: 815 µs per loop
soup.find(): 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.61 ms per loop ; select() is 2 times faster.